# Format of the Export-Csv in Powershell - unexpected column order

Tags: powershell, properties, export-to-csv, pscustomobject

I'm trying to export an array of objects to a .csv file, what do I need to do to put everything in the right column with header of a property name.

I've tried selecting properties by select to pipeline

```
$groups = Get-MsolGroup -All 
$results = @()
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $props = @{
        'DisplayName' = $group.DisplayName
        'GroupType'   = $group.GroupType
        'Email'       = $group.EmailAddress
        'MemberCount' = @(Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $group.ObjectId).Count
    }
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Prop $props 
    $results += $props
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\Tako\Desktop\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: while the usual way is to use `[PSCustomObject]`, you can simply change this line `$props = @{` to this `$props = [ordered]@{` that will give you the items in the same sequence that you define them.

Comment: Lee is right. Please try the code below which would work for you. And if it works, please help mark it as answer as per this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). Thanks.

Comment: I assume that your issue is with the unexpected _order_ in which the columns appear in the CSV file and have updated the title accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your code like below:

```
$groups = Get-MsolGroup -All

$output = $groups | ForEach-Object{
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                "DisplayName" = $_.DisplayName
                "GroupType"   = $_.GroupType
                "Email"       = $_.EmailAddress
                "MemberCount" = @(Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $_.ObjectId).Count
                }
                }


$output | Export-Csv -Path "F:\temp\1\myresults.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Here is a similar test, just test with Get-AzStorageAccount cmdlet:

[image]

Comment: @LotPings, thanks for pointing this out, forgot to change it.

Comment: Your solution is effective, but please also _explain_: point out that you added `[PSCustomObject]` (to take the place of the subsequent `New-Object PSObject` call) and explain what this piece of syntactic sugar does and _why it solves the problem_ (property-definition order is being preserved). The - commendable - switch from explicitly appending to an array incrementally to implicit output collection is also worth mentioning.